# Shape-matching of plots using non-linear least squares

Tags: c++, shapes, matching, numerical-methods, least-squares

What would b the best way to implement a simple shape-matching algorithm to match a plot interpolated from just 8 points (x, y) against a database of similar plots (> 12 000 entries), each plot having >100 nodes. The database has 6 categories of plots (signals measured under 6 different conditions), and the main aim is to find the right category (so for every category there's around 2000 plots to compare against).

The 8-node plot would represent actual data from measurement, but for now I am simulating this by selecting a random plot from the database, then 8 points from it, then smearing it using gaussian random number generator.

What would be the best way to implement non-linear least-squares to compare the shape of the 8-node plot against each plot from the database? Are there any c++ libraries you know of that could help with this?

Is it necessary to find the actual formula (f(x)) of the 8-node plot to use it with least squares, or will it be sufficient to use interpolation in requested points, such as interpolation from the gsl library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use least squares without knowing the actual formula. If all of your plots are measured at the same x value, then this is easy -- you simply compute the sum in the normal way:

[image]

where y_i is a point in your 8-node plot, sigma_i is the error on the point and Y(x_i) is the value of the plot from the database at the same x position as y_i. You can see why this is trivial if all your plots are measured at the same x value.

If they're not, you can get Y(x_i) either by fitting the plot from the database with some function (if you know it) or by interpolating between the points (if you don't know it). The simplest interpolation is just to connect the points with straight lines and find the value of the straight lines at the x_i that you want. [Other interpolations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) might do better.

In my field, we use [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) for these kind of things. However, [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html) has a great collections of functions, and it might be easier to get started with -- if you don't mind using Python.

One major problem you could have would be that the two plots are not independent. [Wikipedia suggests McNemar's test in this case.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test)

Another problem you could have is that you don't have much information in your test plot, so your results will be affected greatly by statistical fluctuations. In other words, if you only have 8 test points and two plots match, how will you know if the underlying functions are really the same, or if the 8 points simply jumped around (inside their error bars) in such a way that it looks like the plot from the database -- purely by chance! ... I'm afraid you won't really know. So the plots that test well will include false positives (low purity), and some of the plots that don't happen to test well were probably actually good matches (low efficiency).

To solve that, you would need to either use a test plot with more points or else bring in other information. If you can throw away plots from the database that you know can't match for other reasons, that will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use ROOT as well, but only for plotting (graphics). For interpolation I've used Gnu Scientific Library. 
Unfortunately there's no possibility of having more than 8 nodes of the plot for comparision, and my tests have shown that Least Squares-based method gives very unsatisfying results (matching correctly only in 9% of the tests). So I'm now in the process of searching for a better way to do it. Thanks for your time and help.